# Get id of element on button click using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have list of dynamic generated buttons and id is generated on run time. how can is get id of clicked button using JQuery.

Here is js code

```
var btn = " <input type='button' id='btnDel' value='Delete' />";


$("#metainfo").append(txt); //set value of

$("#btnDel").attr("id", "btnDel" + $("#hid").attr("value"));
```

Comment: add a class like `generatedButton` or whatever you want to these dynamically created button, and then you can use Jan Willem B's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864327/get-id-of-element-on-button-click-using-jquery/2864340#2864340

Comment: Why do you change the id of the button in the first place? I find that a strange thing to do...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For your example it would be like this:

```
$("#btnDel").click(function() {
  alert(this.id);
});
```

Note that you can't loop the code you have, IDs **have to be unique**, you'll get all sorts of side-effects if they're not, as it's invalid HTML.  If you wanted a click handler for any input, change the selector, like this:

```
$("input").click(function() {
  alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: All dynamic buttons have unique ids and your code is not working.

Comment: @Xulfee - Are you running it **before** you create the button, or after creating it and setting the ID?  If it's before, you'll need to use `.live('click', function() {})` instead of `.click(function() { })`

Answer (score 2):

You should add click event of the button after document is ready(Loaded):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnDel").click(function() {
        alert('Button clicked.');
    });
});
```

Comment: @gsamaras don't shout on him!

Comment: @gsamaras you are awesome

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.generatedButton').click(function() {
  alert(this.id);
});
```

EDIT after you posted the code:

```
var btn = 
  $("<input type='button' value='Delete' />")
    .attr("id", "btnDel" + $("#hid").val())
    .click(function() {
       alert(this.id);
    });
$("body").append(btn);
```

Comment: @Xulfee this is an example how you can add `generatedButton` (without the dot) to the `class`-attribute of your button to find it with jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Comment: the code you posted in your question does not work (for example, the btn var only contains a string with HTML which would result in a button if it was rendered by a browser, but not the button itself), but I updated this answer in an attempt to help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

For any element whether its a button or anything else , we can target it like this

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    console.log(e.target.id) 
  
})
```

Here `e.target.id` gives you the id of the element.