# How to check id of button clicked in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have 2 buttons `"removeD"` and `"updateRecord"`(by id) and I have written same ajax for them as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'DB/tableDisplay.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'id='+uid,
    dataType: 'html'
})
```

But in tableDisplay.php I want to have different functionality for both the buttons.How to check the id of the button clicked in php? 
I've tried using :
`if(isset($_POST['removeD'])){
}else{
}`
But this is not working.

Comment: `var id = $(this).attr('id');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get id of element on button click using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864327/get-id-of-element-on-button-click-using-jquery)

Comment: Manage by onclick event on button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $('body').on('click','#id1',function(){
          $.ajax({
             url : 'url',
             data : {variable:values},
             type : 'html',
             dataType : 'GET/POST',
             success : function(data){
               console.log('Message after Success');
    },
             error : function(){
               console.log('Error Message')
    }

});
});
```

In your url page you can find whether ajax request is posted or not

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST['variable'])){
        write your php code here........
}
```

Comment: In the above snippet you posted:if(isset($_REQUEST['variable'])){
        write your php code here........
} . What should I write in 'variable'? I wrote the the "id" of the button there, but it's not working. Please help.

Comment: @PranaliNinawe  did you checked others answer?

Comment: in variable you can pass any thing on which you can check whether you want to delete , update or add the record so that you can write code accordingly

Comment: you can also pass multiple variables like data : {id:id,name:name} etc

Comment: Thank you so much ! It was really helpful !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('button').click(function(){

     var id = $(this).attr('id');

     $.ajax({
        url: 'DB/tableDisplay.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id: id},
        dataType: 'html'
      })

  });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to detect the button clicked:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.click-button').on('click',function () {
            var button_id = $(this).attr('id');
            if(button_id == 'removeD'){
                alert('removeD button clicked');
            }else if(button_id == 'updateRecord'){
                alert('updateRecord button clicked');
            }

        });


    });
</script>

</head>

<input type="button" class="click-button" id="removeD" value="removeD">

<input type="button" class="click-button" id="updateRecord" value="updateRecord">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) it return which DOM element triggered the event. see below code its too easy and short to get id of clicked element.

```js
 $('button').click(function(e){
      alert(e.target.id);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="remove">Remove</button><br>
<button id="update">Update</button><br>
```